# Black dots on fins and body of betta

Tags: diseases

My betta has developed some black spots between it's fins and body. I noticed this a week before. I feel that the spots are now increasing and the betta is looking worse. We moved him to a bowl once we noticed it

This betta had to be shifted twice and the journey was barely half a day. But after the second journey our betta seems to be a little less energetic and always sleeping in that little cave of his. He is responding to me gently tapping the tank and does eat his food but him sleeping all the time is making me worried. This betta is not very old. I reckon he's about 8 months old right now. Does anybody have any idea what this is or how I can make him feel better. (Ps medicines are not readily available here and the climate nowadays is horrible) [image: my betta's current condition]

Comment: Did you made a water test? How did you started the tank? Is there any technic like pump and filter? Do you, and if yes how often, do water changes?

Comment: The parameters of the water are normal. The bowl which I moved it into does not have any filter as such but it's previous tank did. I do water changes about every 4-5 days.

Comment: What is normal? Do you have numbers?